# Running ubuntu vagrant server won't show anything on debian local browser

Tags: python, django, debian, vagrant, pycharm

I've done this multiple times and never had an issue.

I'm trying to run a website on vagrant (trusty64) through shh on my Debian 8 Jessie x64.

I have used the same `Vagrantfile` n times before and it always worked perfectly but for I don't know what reason, on my new laptop, when I enter (on vagrant server - tried with `sudo` and without):

`vagrant up`
`vagrant ssh`
`cd /opt/site/`
`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

nothing happens in console. It shows the usual:

```
System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
October 28, 2015 - 10:16:41
Django version 1.8.4, using settings 'settings.development'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

and when I type the `ip:port` in my local browser it just say:

```
This webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Any workaround for this ?

**My vagrant config file:**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 512
  end
  config.vm.box = "trusty64"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.100.10"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/opt/site"
  config.vm.hostname = "alexander"
end
```

*As a mention*: I tried multiple ports and still nothing. More, I have the exactly same configuration on another pc and it works flawless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If changing the port forwarding doesn't work.You might also need to change in the settings of virtual box from `NAT` to `Bridged Adapter`.

Answer (score 1):

The firewall will block incoming traffix on port 8000, so you will have to [forward that port](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html). Try adding this this to the configuration.  you're using:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8080
```

and then browse to http://192.168.100.10:8080 it should work.

Also dont forget to privision your box again, or even restart just to be sure.

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

Why it works on your other machine is a mystery to me. Maybe there is no firewall, or the port is already forwarded?

Comment: I did what you said and I get the same mesage in my browser. I also reloaded the vagrant machine. Any other ideas ?